# Is there a way of testing in Postman if the body respons of a variable contains text or numbers?

Tags: api, testing, automated-tests, numbers, postman

I want to test an API endpoint GET, where through this I retrieve a list of abbreviations which have an ID number. This is a snippet of how the respons body looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 11,
        "text": "A.D."
    },
{
        "id": 29,
        "text": "a.m."
    }
```

From here I want to test if all "text" instances contain abbreviations and not numbers.

I tried this 2 ways, but clearly is not working:

```
pm.test("Id includes a number", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.include(Number);
});
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
pm.test("Text check", function () { 
    pm.expect(jsonData.text).is.to.equal(parseInt());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response data is array, it started `[` and ended `]`

So you needs to access item by index  then can access content by key.

And this console.log() can help to figure out it.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData.length)
console.log(jsonData[0])
console.log(jsonData[1])
console.log(jsonData[0]["id"])
console.log(jsonData[0]["text"])
console.log(jsonData[1]["id"])
console.log(jsonData[1]["text"])

pm.test("Id includes a number", function () {
    pm.expect(jsonData[0]["id"]).to.equal(11);
});

pm.test("Text check", function () { 
    pm.expect(jsonData[0]["text"]).is.to.equal("A.D.");
});
```

[image: test results in Postman]

[image: console result]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is very helpful, I am not familiar with Postman. I have written test in Python, and I see they are very different. My list of abbreviations is very long, and I didn't want to write them one by one. So your answer is half helpful. But thank you very much!

Comment: I am happy to hear, it help to your job!